# How to edit x axis with pylab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my graph, but it seems like over line x axis after 9. Anyone can help me to edit it? [image]

Comment: can you show us the code you used to create this graph?  It is hard to debug code we can not see ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the x limits with a range, using either pyplot's `xlim` or with the object oriented interface `ax.set_xlim`. Both take a range as arguments.  So if you wanted to set the x-axis to be between 5 and 10, you just do:

`plt.xlim((5,10))`

---

### Example Graph

Given some initial boilerplate to set up a graph:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim((0, 2100))
ax.bar(0, 2000, width=5)
ax.bar(100, 500, width=5)
ax.bar(40, 1500, width=5)
```

You can then use `set_xlim` to change the x limits:

```
ax.set_xlim((-50,150))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-50, 150, 20))
plt.show()
```

[image: Example Bar Graph]

---

### Generalizing + Log Scales

More generally, it's `plt.xlim(left, right)` where left and right are the left and right boundaries you want for the graph.  The units are always going to be the same as the data you feed in. Even if you use a log scale, the values you pass to `xlim` will be applied to the normal scale (e.g., `(0, 100)` would go to `(0, 10**2)` on the log graph)

You can use it with a log scale just the same way (but it's a bit finickier).  To get a log scale, you just need to change the xscale with `ax.set_xscale("log")`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the axis bounds with `pylab.xlim`.

Comment: then how to use pylab.xlim? Can we use log inside xlim?